# How to change the order of my app screenshots?

Tags: ios

I have had my app approved by apple and it now says Ready for Sale.  However I want to change the order of the screenshots.  I repeat, only the order. I do not want to change or edit images, just want to change the order.  I understand editing and changing images is not allowed once the app is ready for sale - thats fine.  But surely there must be a way to change the order of the screenshots!!?

Answer (score 0):

No there is now to change the order only, any changes require a update.

This was possible, but due to some developer misusing the option to change screenshots after the app was reviewed with functionality which was not in the app Apple has disabled any edit of meta data.
Only the app description is editable.

Comment: @user3163428 You might find it sick, but due to developers selling apps that where just completely different then the screenshots presented them to be and make money is even more sick. This happens all time on both platforms but Apple is trying to at least try and stop it.

Comment: rckoenes: Reading the question is the key here!!  I said changing the order of the already approved screenshots NOT editing or adding new screenshots! How is not allowing changing the order of the screenshots they already approved a fight against what you have mentioned??

Comment: Because order is seen as editing, I do agree with you, but to change the order you have to edit the screenshots of you app. Which is not allowed. Besides I'm not representing Apple, you issue is with the them. Just send in a bug report where you state that changing the order is not edit and it should be allowed.

Comment: thanks.  I did that already.  But knowing their attitude firmly instilled by their deceased founder- who once famously told the IBM CEO "I will bury you" and of course did not -  I am not holding my breath!

Comment: Dude project your anger else where this will break you up.